# Wordpress CSS Navigation Menu on hover take effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

so I'm building a wordpress website and I have some products sub-menus in a megamenu. I wanna make so when a hover a sub-menu product link to show a specific image in column 4 of the megamenu. I've tryed many options with css but can't figure it out.

So, as an exemple I've gave one link a special class ".pricomigdale" and the image ".pricomigdale-img" with a "display:none" so when I hover on "Pricomigdale de cocos" to take action like this ".pricomigdale a:hover .pricomigdale-img {display:block}" but nothing happen. Here's the website maybe someone can figure it out: https://thefitbaker.ro

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSqel.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some relevant code to your question. You also may want to consider posting this on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, which is specifically for WP-related questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to eat your products ;)

I think it might be helpful if you would post a bit more of your code.

I just recognized that you left out a semicolon here: {display:block}

It should be {display:block;}

But I am not sure if that would solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

I think this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44xq250x/) can help you

The point is that you create attribute with your links, for example `data-image` with url of necessary image

And use JS to make your image changing on hover

```
$('a').hover(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#photo-container').html('<img src="' + $(this).data('image') + '"/>')
});
```

Comment: Ok, that should work but you know a way how can I add data-image in some of the wordpress sub-menu links?